# Create list of items of a single item at once

Tags: angularjs, object-initialization

Angular task 1.5.x:

I have object like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "a",
    items: [
        {"holiday": "false", "day": "monday"}, 
        {"holiday": "true", "day": "tuesday"...}
    ]
}
```

I want a new object to be created in the above way with click of a single button. Note I dont want to add each item separately, all at once. Means, for a single object with name "a", I want to add all items for all days at once.

I can make it work but I want to know the correct way.

ultimately we should be able to create a javascript object in the above format(without id)(I think this format is correct) and send it to server so it will work. But how to add html/angular code so I will get an object that way.

Please let me know for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `ng-model` you do not have to fully define your object in order to have it constructed. E.g.:

**Controller**

```
$scope.object= {
    items: [] 
};

var n = 7;
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
    $scope.object.items({});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="object.name"/>

<div ng-repeat="currObj in object.items">
    <input type="text" ng-model="currObj.holiday" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="currObj.day" />
</div>
```

The general structure must be defined beforehand, but you do not have to initialize all the properties. They will receive values when binding is triggered (view -> model).

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this :

Create a button in your view and use `ng-click` directive to capture on click event.

**Html:**

```
<button ng-click="createCopy()"></button>
```

Use [**angular.copy**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) to create a deep copy of the source object.

This is what `angular.copy` does as explained in the docs :

> Creates a deep copy of source, which should be an object or an array.
>
> If no destination is supplied, a copy of the object or array is
>   created. If a destination is provided, all of its elements (for
>   arrays) or properties (for objects) are deleted and then all
>   elements/properties from the source are copied to it. If source is not
>   an object or array (inc. null and undefined), source is returned. If
>   source is identical to destination an exception will be thrown.

**Controller:**

```
$scope.mainObject = { id: 1, name: "a", items: [{"holiday": "false", "day": "monday"}, {"holiday": "true", "day": "tuesday"...}] };

$scope.createCopy = function (){    
  $scope.copyObject = angular.copy($scope.mainObject);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but my question is - For a single object with name "a", how to add data for multiple days at once - for monday, tues .. sunday.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that, Can you just add the expected output in your question?